# How to "modularize" my Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to break up my large, monlithic Jenkins jobs into smaller, re-usable parts.

The standard way of doing this, by saving off and reading artifacts, is problematic for me.  Our workspace is so large that it takes almost half an hour to save and copy the artifacts from one job to another.  If I break my large job into four smaller jobs, that would had two whole hours to my build.  This is simply unacceptable.

It seems that there ought to be a way of doing one of the following:

When JobA ends, have JobB run *immediately*, on the same node, and in the same workspace as JobA.

JobA triggers JobB which runs *immediately* and on the same node and workspace, and then returns back to JobA which continues on from that point.

But neither of these seems to be possible in Jenkins.

What am I missing?  How am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can define several build steps in your project. And you can use the 'template' plugin which allows to use the build rules from another project, thus giving you some modularity.

An alternative approach might be to use the 'Parametrized trigger' plugin and call the same job in the 'post build phase' with different parameters - possibly the parameter being analysed in conjunction with the 'conditional buildstep' plugin, running different build steps depending on their values.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you run on the same node you can access the workspace folder of any job from any other job. So you can do something with the artifacts of JobA inside JobB. You simply need to define the JobA's workspace folder as the working directory for your build scripts. It's much easier when you use batch/sh scripts mainly to do the work.
You can trigger JobB automatically everytime JobA has been built successfully via a build trigger in JobB.